# How do you change the detailViewController in a method

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, view

I have a view that is doing a lot of functions and when I get to the point that I am done I want to change to a `newViewcontroller`. if I where to do this from the rootview I just call.

```
NewPageViewController *newDetailViewController = [[NewPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewPageViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
```

But I need to do it from my old detail (the right side)

I am downloading a file in a splitview iPad app from the right side and after the file is downloaded I need to in my method change the right side of the splitview to a new nib file so I can open and edit the file

Can someone point me in the right way.

Now I have :

```
-(void)changeView { 

    ListController *newDetailViewController = [[ListController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListController"bundle:nil]

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0], newDetailViewController, nil];

    splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    [viewControllers release];

}

-(void)downloadfile {
 //I do all my work and get the file.
NSLog(@"I need to change views now.");


                [self changeView];

}
```

I don't get any errors but the right side view is not changing.

Comment: Hey Chris, your question is not very clear. What exactly you want to do? If you can explain it in a better way then I can help you out accordingly. :)

Comment: Are you sure your RHS view is not changing? Is it the case that it's changing, but looks no different to the view that was already there? Are you calling downloadfile on the main thread btw? (you should be). Is downloadfile definitely getting called? Your NSLog gets output, right?

Comment: Also, put in an NSLog to check that splitViewController isn't null - you might have not hooked up the IBOutlet from Interface Builder?

Comment: Ok it looks null. Assertion failed: (splitViewController.viewControllers != nil), function -[ListController changeView]

Comment: So did you hook up the UISplitViewController then? Sounds like you forgot to. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry just had time to get back of this and it did help me thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an `NSArray *viewControllers` property on the `UISplitViewController` class. The first item in this array is your master VC, the second in the detail VC. Re-assign this property to a new array containing the same master VC but a new details VC:

```
// don't forget to set the delegate of myNewDetailViewController appropriately!
myNewDetailViewController.delegate = ...

NSArray newVCs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[uiSplitVC.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0], myNewDetailViewController, nil];

uiSplitVC.viewControllers = newVCs;
```

API ref for UISplitViewController: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

**N.B: do not try replacing the master VC** -- it usually goes horribly wrong somehow. [I tried many many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763745/uisplitviewcontroller-cannot-change-the-master-view-controller/4224658#4224658) of replacing the master, it always went wrong in some very annoying way.  Replacing the detail VC is fine though!

Comment: I added what i have now still having a problem.

Answer (score 9):

As of iOS8 you can use the `-showDetailViewController:sender:` method on the UISplitViewController.  See the [Apple docs on UISplitViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISplitViewController/showDetailViewController:sender:).

Answer (score 0):

As @chris mentioned you can the use Delegate of UISplitViewController for iOS 8 and above which is the best possible way.

```
 -(void)showDetailViewController:(UIViewController *)vc sender:(nullable id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```